# How to traverse a particular node's descendant node based on some other descendant's value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an example xml as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
            <topic>
        <table>...</table>
        <p>...</p>
        <ul>

              <li>there is a tag
        <b>
    <u>HERE an XREF tag </u>
    </b>has to be added after the fn tag that point to the fn id 
    <fn id="id-523">this is a second fn with id-523</fn>
    </li>
      <li>there is another third
    <fn id="id-524">this is a third  fn  id-524</fn>
        </li>
              <li>there is another fourth
 <fn id="id-525">this is a fourth  fn  id-525</fn>
    <xref href="#topic_gtc_yn2_bcb/id-525" format="dita" type="fn"/>
    </li>
              <li>there is a xref  tag that points to the fn id-523 
    <xref href="#topic_gtc_yn2_bcb/id-523" format="dita" type="fn"/>
    </li>
            </ul>
        </topic>
```

Now here I have to check the id attribute present inside the fn tag.
If corresponding to that id I have an xref tag inside the same ul (it can be for a table or ol element as well)then remove the id attribute else I=if I have an xref tag with same id(here for eg id=523).
Then I have to introduce xref tag just after that particular fn tag.

Expected output therefore will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
        <topic>
    <table>...</table>
    <p>...</p>
    <ul>

          <li>there is another tag
    <b>
<u>HERE an XREF tag </u>
</b>has to be added after the fn tag that point to the fn id 
       <fn id="id-523">this is a second fn with id-523</fn>
<xref href="#topic_gtc_yn2_bcb/id-523" format="dita" type="fn"/>
    </li>
      <li>there is another third
<fn>this is a third  fn  id-524</fn>
    </li>
          <li>there is another fourth <fn id="id-525">this is a fourth  fn  id-525</fn>
<xref href="#topic_gtc_yn2_bcb/id-525" format="dita" type="fn"/>
</li>
          <li>there is a xref  tag that points to the fn id-523 
<xref href="#topic_gtc_yn2_bcb/id-523" format="dita" type="fn"/>
</li>
        </ul>
    </topic>
```

Comment: As a starting point,I am trying to use something as below:
<xsl:template match="ul[descendant::fn]">
  
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="//fn[@id=//xref[@href]]">
       <xref id="1"></xref>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>

      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    
  </xsl:template>

Comment: So do you have `fn` elements in the XML input or simply text like `&lt;fn`?

Comment: I have to apply it on <fn> tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fn[@id]">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="concat('#topic_gtc_yn2_bcb/', @id)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="ancestor::*[matches(name(), '^(ul|table|ol)$')]//xref/@href  = $id">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="ancestor::*[matches(name(), '^(ul|table|ol)$')]//xref/@href  = $id">
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[1][self::xref/@href = $id])">
            <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::*[matches(name(), '^(ul|table|ol)$')]//xref[@href  = $id]"></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```